# Is there any sql performance gain for using underscores instead of spaces?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, performance

Is there any potential speed increase in using underscores instead of words with spaces in a query?

For example, searching a column named "label" for "specific_label" vs "specific label"?

Comment: A character is a character, is a character... ;)

Comment: No. It's "%20". (Lose the quotes)

Comment: BTW, that's another question. I'd love to get more reputation by just saying "No" :)

Comment: Yeah, I knew the answer to that one (which I believe is why I assumed it would affect an SQL query), but I was looking for OMG Ponies response in regards to "A character is a character".

Comment: He's right. So is my answer. But explaining why %20 is one character requires a new question :) Hint: the answer has to do with encoding

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No.

Comment: Well, it **was** a Yes/No question!

Comment: This is true! It is funny the things we assume to be true for no apparent reason. I am glad I asked. Thank you.

Comment: Always glad to help! (my usual state)

Comment: There is a user in SO called *Downvoter Step into the Light* (or something like that). I like that.

Answer (score 2):

No. A system as mature as an SQL Server would not treat identifiers with a space and different from and other character.

Comment: Yeah, I missed out an "an"... or should that be an "a"... heading off to English.stackexchange

Answer (score 2):

Not really but there are other benefits to do so.

1. Not every DBMS supports spaces for column names -> Migrations will be easier
2. Your SQL Queries use less quotations -> Better readability and less errors

Comment: Thank you for the response, I was referring to the column value, not the name.

Answer (score 1):

Of course not. That would be like asking, "Would there be a performance increase if I called column 'fname' instead of 'firstname'"

A name is a name and queries execute just as fast no matter what characters you use

Comment: Thank you for the response, I was referring to the column value, not the name, but the answer appears to be the same regardless.